# When a question gets below a threshold we should be able to vote to delete

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-delete

When an answer gets below a certain threshold users with the correct privileges are able to vote to delete.

On questions this only happens if the question is **closed**

I am proposing creating a threshold for allowance of delete votes ***before*** the question is closed.

This could possibly be a 20 or 15K privilege.
I am suggesting a threshold of `-10`

Comment: I don't read why you propose it. Is the current system not sufficient? Does this solve any problems?

Comment: @Bart I propose it due to the fact that some *really bad* questions somehow do not get closed, but they do acquire many downvotes

Comment: If you cant get the close votes, what makes you think that you can get the delete votes?

Comment: @JoshMein you could be surprised....

Comment: -10....time to delete?

Comment: @Jim that _may_ be....

Comment: Hey, welcome back to Meta!

Comment: @YannisRizos ha.... thanks.... :-\ I see i was missed :-(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Questions should in most cases be closed before being deleted, the only exception is spam or offensive content. For those there are the flags that cause deletion, so manual deletion is usually not necessary.

In all other cases, allowing quicker deletion instead of just closure could make it harder for the community to review such decisions. Deleted questions are nearly invisible, they don't get the kind of review merely closed questions can. Allowing users to delete questions without closing them is also likely to be thoroughly confusing to the owner of the question.

Comment: And it makes it more difficult for the Reopen system to work.

Comment: @Almo well there **are** undelete votes

Comment: True, but as Mad Scientist said, deleted questions are almost invisible.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Deleted questions are extremely hard to find if you aren't a mod and don't have the direct link. It is pretty much impossible for the community to properly review question deletions

Comment: @MadScientist that is true....